# socket close(sd) call (after sending arp request) is getting stuck (hanged)

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

The below `create_and_send_arp` function sometimes hangs in the `close(sd)` call, after sending an ARP request.  Is that due to creating the socket with `htons (ETH_P_ALL)` ? I think for sending Gratuitous ARP requests it should be `htons (ETH_P_ARP)`.

Would there be any side effect if we changed the socket protocol type to `ETH_P_ARP` instead of `ETH_P_ALL`?

```
create_and_send_arp(string port, IpAddress& addr)
{
    const char *interface;
    int frame_length, sd, bytes;
    arp_hdr arphdr;
    UINT32 address = addr.addr.ipv4.s_addr;

    uint8_t src_ip[4], src_mac[6], dst_mac[6], ether_frame[IP_MAXPACKET];
    struct sockaddr_ll device;
    struct ifreq ifr;


    // Interface to send packet through.
    interface = port.c_str();
    memcpy (src_ip, &address, 4 * sizeof (uint8_t));

     // Submit request for a socket descriptor to look up interface.
    if ((sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0) {
      perror ("socket() failed to get socket descriptor for using ioctl()");
      return;
    }

    // Use ioctl() to look up interface name and get its MAC address.
    memset (&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
    snprintf (ifr.ifr_name, sizeof (ifr.ifr_name), "%s", interface);
    if (ioctl (sd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) < 0) {
      perror ("ioctl() failed to get source MAC address");
      close (sd);
      return;
    }

    close (sd);

    // Copy source MAC address.
    memcpy (src_mac, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));

    // Find interface index from interface name and store index in
    // struct sockaddr_ll device, which will be used as an argument of sendto().
    if ((device.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex (interface)) == 0) {
      perror ("if_nametoindex() failed to obtain interface index");
      return;
    }

    // Set destination MAC address: broadcast address
    memset (dst_mac, 0xff, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));

    memcpy (&arphdr.sender_ip, src_ip, 4 * sizeof (uint8_t));
    memcpy (&arphdr.target_ip, src_ip, 4 * sizeof (uint8_t));

    // Fill out sockaddr_ll.
    device.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    memcpy (device.sll_addr, src_mac, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));
    device.sll_halen = htons (6);

    // ARP header

    // Hardware type (16 bits): 1 for ethernet
    arphdr.htype = htons (1);

    // Protocol type (16 bits): 2048 for IP
    arphdr.ptype = htons (ETH_P_IP);

    // Hardware address length (8 bits): 6 bytes for MAC address
    arphdr.hlen = 6;

    // Protocol address length (8 bits): 4 bytes for IPv4 address
    arphdr.plen = 4;

    // OpCode: 1 for ARP request
    arphdr.opcode = htons (ARPOP_REQUEST);

    // Sender hardware address (48 bits): MAC address
    memcpy (&arphdr.sender_mac, src_mac, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));

    // Target hardware address (48 bits): zero
    memset (&arphdr.target_mac, 0, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));

    // Fill out ethernet frame header.

    // Ethernet frame length = ethernet header (MAC + MAC + ethernet type) + ethernet data (ARP header)
    frame_length = 6 + 6 + 2 + ARP_HDRLEN;

    // Destination and Source MAC addresses
    memcpy (ether_frame, dst_mac, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));
    memcpy (ether_frame + 6, src_mac, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));

    // Next is ethernet type code (ETH_P_ARP for ARP).
    ether_frame[12] = ETH_P_ARP / 256;
    ether_frame[13] = ETH_P_ARP % 256;


    // ARP header
    memcpy (ether_frame + ETH_HDRLEN, &arphdr, ARP_HDRLEN * sizeof (uint8_t));

    if ((sd = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ARP))) < 0) {
        perror ("socket() failed");
        return;
    }

    // Send ethernet frame to socket.
    if ((bytes = sendto (sd, ether_frame, frame_length, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &device, sizeof (device))) <= 0) {
      perror ("sendto() failed");
      close (sd);
      return;
    }

    // Close socket descriptor.
    close (sd); // this gets stuck and hangs
    return;
    }
```

The backtrace when the program hangs is

```
[New LWP 29815]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

#0 0x00007f33984cf750 in __close_nocancel () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#0 0x00007f33984cf750 in __close_nocancel () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

Comment: The partial backtrace indicates that your program is multithreaded, and it furthermore seems to be indicating that you have two threads both running `close()` at the same time (not necessarily corresponding to the same source line).  Multithreading provides all kinds of opportunities for intermittent failures, so a reasonable diagnostic step would be to try to reproduce the issue in a single-threaded program.

Comment: we are firing a timer (using libevent), inside timer expiry call back function we are calling this ARP request send method. So it might happen that libevent is creating threads internally for each timer event and calling the callback function from that thread. Which eventually calls create_and_send_arp method.

Comment: The posted question is about a run time problem.  SO, please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: It seems the OP could have made that minor edit in their program to `htons (ETH_P_ARP).` and tested it out (and IMO: should have done so) before posting the question on stackoverflow